# Ternary operator precedence

Tags: ruby

I am using the ternary operator in this example, which works fine:

```
out = 'demo'.start_with?('No information provided') ? 'No information provided' : 'Confidential'
```

When I apply this to `<<` operator, I got an exception `can't convert true into String`:

```
out << 'demo'.start_with?('No information provided') ? 'No information provided' : 'Confidential'
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<<` has higher precedence then `?` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

So

```
out << 'demo'.start_with?('No information provided') ? 'No information provided' : 'Confidential'
```

is actually as

```
(out << 'demo'.start_with?('No information provided')) ? 'No information provided' : 'Confidential'
```

As per the error `out` is string object, and [`String#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) required its argument also a *string*. But `'demo'.start_with?('No information provided')` gives a `true` object, so you got the error *'can't convert true into String'*, as there was statement like `(out << true) ? .. : ..`.

Be safe always by using paren `(..)` to avoid such precedence problem.

```
out << ('demo'.start_with?('No information provided') ? 'No information provided' : 'Confidential')
```